# How to avoid returning to the command prompt when running gnome-terminal

Tags: shell, gnome-terminal, xterm

When I run `gnome-terminal` from the command line and hit return, the shell prompt appears immediately when the gnome-terminal window is open, as if `gnome-terminal &` was executed. This is unlike `xterm`, which will not return to the shell prompt unless it is started in the background.

My question is how I can start gnome-terminal in the foreground the same way as xterm, such that it won't return to the shell prompt after entering return unless I explicitly run `gnome-terminal &`?

Comment: @don_crissti `gnome-terminal --disable-factory` works